# Artificial perceptron in python3

Tags: python, performance, object-oriented, python-3.x, neural-network

I have designed a very basic perceptron (single layer neural network) that has been mostly successful in learning basic linearly separable problems.

The perceptron in defined as a class with different functions for training and running it and is mostly constructed with lists.

```
from math import tanh
from random import randint

class perceptron():

    def __init__(self, n_inputs): # initialize random weights and settings

        self.inputs = []
        self.outputs = [0]
        self.weights_in = []
        self.weights_out = []

        self.training_speed = 0.1

        for a in range(n_inputs): self.inputs.append(0)

        for c in range(n_inputs): self.weights_in.append(randint(0,9)/10)

        self.weights_out.append(randint(0,9)/10)


    def run(self, input_): # single forward loop through perceptron

        for e in range(len(self.inputs)): # assign inputs

            self.inputs[e] = input_[e]

        total = 0

        for f in range(len(self.weights_in)): # calculate node value

            total += self.inputs[f] * self.weights_in[f]

        first = tanh(total) # activation function
        output = []

        for g in range(len(self.outputs)): # calculate outputs

            output.append( tanh( first * self.weights_out[g] ) )

        return output, first

    def train(self, input_, expected_output): # tarin perceptron with known data

        test = self.run(input_)
        guess = test[0]
        errors_in = []
        error = []

        for h in range(len(self.weights_in)): # find error for each input

            errors_in.append( (guess[0]- test[1]) - expected_output )

        for i in range(len(self.weights_out)): # find error for each output

            error.append( guess[0] - expected_output )

        for j in range(len(self.weights_out)): # change output weights

            self.weights_out[j] = ( self.weights_out[j] - error[j] * test[1] * self.training_speed )

        for k in range(len(self.weights_in)): # change input weights

            self.weights_in[k] = ( self.weights_in[k] - errors_in[k] * input_[k] * self.training_speed )

        print(error) # print the total error
```

I hope to be able to join multiple of these in the future to make a multi-layer network, but as it is now it runs very slow. I used a loop to train the perceptron by generating random numbers, calculating the true answer and passing it into the training function of the network.

Does anyone know of a way to make it more efficient when training? I have looked at different training speeds, but the faster i make it using that, the less accurate it will be.

Comment: I suspect this code doesn't work as intended. In the `train` method, the two first loops never use the `h` and `i` parameters and the code inside the loop doesn't make sense without them.